# Identity server 4 OpenId Connect redirect to /Account/AccessDenied

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, openid-connect, identityserver4

I have raised a bug on Github but wanted to see if anyone where could help aswell. [Bug #1839](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1839)

**Issue / Steps to reproduce the problem**

*I am trying to use openId Connect to authenticate against our azure ad but after the callback method I get redirected to /Account/AccessDenied*

*Once authentication is complete azure redirects back to the callback method.*

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Post processing of external authentication. Callback from azure.
    /// </summary>
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> TprUserLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        // read external identity from the temporary cookie
        var claimsPrincipal = await HttpContext.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);

        if (claimsPrincipal == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("External authentication error");
        }

        var claimResult = externalClaimsMapper.Map(claimsPrincipal);
        var claims = claimResult.Claims.ToArray();

        await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(claimResult.UserId, claimResult.UserName, claimResult.Provider, claims);

        return Redirect(interactionService.IsValidReturnUrl(returnUrl) ? returnUrl : "~/");
    }
```

*The Redirect then seems to go off into the asp core middleware (v1.1.3) which adds an entry into the log saying the cookie was forbidden.*

> 2017-12-06 11:01:13,920 [40] INFO 
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware.Log
>   - AuthenticationScheme: idsrv.external was forbidden and after that the page redirects to /Account/AccessDenied.
>
> 2017-12-06 11:01:13,921 [40] INFO 
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectMiddleware.Log
>   - AuthenticationScheme: OpenIdConnect was forbidden.

*Startup - cookie auth and openid connect auth*

```
app.UseIdentityServer();

        var appSettings = container.GetInstance<AppSettings>();

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme,
            AutomaticAuthenticate = false,
            AutomaticChallenge = false,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(appSettings.DefaultTokenLifetimeInMinutes)
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {
            ClientId = appSettings.AzureClientId,
            Authority = appSettings.AzureAuthority,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = appSettings.AzurePostLogoutRedirectUri,
            DisplayName = "TPR Login",
            SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme,
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
            SaveTokens = true,
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false // F5's HTTPS handling so traffic will be HTTP
        });

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCors("default");

        app.UseMvc(ConfigureRoutes.Configure);
```

*After you are redirected the users has been signed in and can access apps if you navigate to the url manually*

**Relevant parts of the log file**

> 2017-12-06 11:01:13,899 [40] INFO 
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Log - Request starting
>   HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:44362/   2017-12-06 11:01:13,900 [40]
>   DEBUG
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Log
>   - Performing unprotect operation to key {144dcece-5570-4965-a74c-0ec3aed546e8} with purposes
>   ('C:\code\tfs03\Single Sign
>   On\Login\ReleaseSSO-Dev\WebUI\Login.IdentityServer',
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware',
>   'idsrv', 'v2'). 2017-12-06 11:01:13,902 [40] INFO 
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware.Log
>   - HttpContext.User merged via AutomaticAuthentication from authenticationScheme: idsrv. 2017-12-06 11:01:13,904 [40] INFO 
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware.Log
>   - AuthenticationScheme: idsrv was successfully authenticated. 2017-12-06 11:01:13,905 [40] DEBUG
>   IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter.Log - No endpoint entry found
>   for request path: / 2017-12-06 11:01:13,906 [40] DEBUG
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Log - The
>   request path / does not match a supported file type 2017-12-06
>   11:01:13,909 [40] DEBUG Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteBase.Log -
>   Request successfully matched the route with name 'default' and
>   template '{controller=Login}/{action=Login}'. 2017-12-06 11:01:13,910
>   [40] DEBUG Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionSelector.Log -
>   Action 'Login.IdentityServer.Controllers.LoginController.Login
>   (Login.IdentityServer)' with id 'cba23692-b89e-4fe7-bf59-ccc14c18352a'
>   did not match the constraint
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.HttpMethodActionConstraint'
>   2017-12-06 11:01:13,911 [40] DEBUG
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Log -
>   Executing action
>   Login.IdentityServer.Controllers.LoginController.Login
>   (Login.IdentityServer) 2017-12-06 11:01:13,913 [40] INFO 
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Log -
>   Executing action method
>   Login.IdentityServer.Controllers.LoginController.Login
>   (Login.IdentityServer) with arguments () - ModelState is Valid
>   2017-12-06 11:01:13,914 [40] DEBUG
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Log -
>   Executed action method
>   Login.IdentityServer.Controllers.LoginController.Login
>   (Login.IdentityServer), returned result
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult. 2017-12-06 11:01:13,915 [40]
>   INFO  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult.Log - Executing
>   ChallengeResult with authentication schemes (OpenIdConnect).
>   2017-12-06 11:01:13,917 [40] DEBUG
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Log
>   - Performing unprotect operation to key {144dcece-5570-4965-a74c-0ec3aed546e8} with purposes
>   ('C:\code\tfs03\Single Sign
>   On\Login\ReleaseSSO-Dev\WebUI\Login.IdentityServer',
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware',
>   'idsrv.external', 'v2'). 2017-12-06 11:01:13,918 [40] INFO 
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware.Log
>   - AuthenticationScheme: idsrv.external was successfully authenticated. 2017-12-06 11:01:13,920 [40] INFO 
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware.Log
>   - AuthenticationScheme: idsrv.external was forbidden. 2017-12-06 11:01:13,921 [40] INFO 
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectMiddleware.Log
>   - AuthenticationScheme: OpenIdConnect was forbidden. 2017-12-06 11:01:13,922 [40] INFO 
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Log -
>   Executed action Login.IdentityServer.Controllers.LoginController.Login
>   (Login.IdentityServer) in 10.0229ms 2017-12-06 11:01:13,924 [40] DEBUG
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Log - Connection id
>   "0HL9SILL2SM7P" completed keep alive response. 2017-12-06 11:01:13,926
>   [40] INFO  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Log - Request
>   finished in 26.936ms 302  2017-12-06 11:01:13,930 [24] INFO 
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Log - Request starting
>   HTTP/1.1 GET
>   http://localhost:44362/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2Flogin%2Ftpruserlogincallback
>   2017-12-06 11:01:13,932 [24] DEBUG
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Log
>   - Performing unprotect operation to key {144dcece-5570-4965-a74c-0ec3aed546e8} with purposes
>   ('C:\code\tfs03\Single Sign
>   On\Login\ReleaseSSO-Dev\WebUI\Login.IdentityServer',
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware',
>   'idsrv', 'v2'). 2017-12-06 11:01:13,934 [24] INFO 
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware.Log
>   - HttpContext.User merged via AutomaticAuthentication from authenticationScheme: idsrv. 2017-12-06 11:01:13,935 [24] INFO 
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware.Log
>   - AuthenticationScheme: idsrv was successfully authenticated. 2017-12-06 11:01:13,936 [24] DEBUG
>   IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter.Log - No endpoint entry found
>   for request path: /Account/AccessDenied 2017-12-06 11:01:13,938 [24]
>   DEBUG Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Log - The
>   request path /Account/AccessDenied does not match a supported file
>   type 2017-12-06 11:01:13,940 [24] DEBUG
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteBase.Log - Request successfully
>   matched the route with name 'default' and template
>   '{controller=Login}/{action=Login}'. 2017-12-06 11:01:13,941 [24]
>   DEBUG Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.MvcRouteHandler.Log - No
>   actions matched the current request 2017-12-06 11:01:13,943 [24] DEBUG
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Log - Request did not
>   match any routes. 2017-12-06 11:01:13,945 [24] DEBUG
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Log - Connection id
>   "0HL9SILL2SM7P" completed keep alive response. 2017-12-06 11:01:13,946
>   [24] INFO  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Log - Request
>   finished in 15.7755ms 404

Answer (score 0):

I recently experienced the same issue, the cause was that a cookie was not being removed during sign out. In my case I found that the **CookieName** property I had set in my **CookieAuthenticationOptions** in StartUp.cs was causing the problem.

While investigating the issue in the browser I noticed that cookie was not being created with this name but instead was using "idsvr.external". Removing the cookie name setting resolved the issue for me.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions)
{
    ...
    CookieName = "...",
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I wasn't able to raise any event like "OnAuthenticationFailed" or "OnRemoteFailure" I just created the action and the view it automatically redirects to. It works, though I know this is not the best way.